# How to only show sub-categories of current category (FSE, block editor)

Tags: categories, full-site-editing

On my Categories archive pages, I'd like to show the subcategories of the current category.

This is with Twenty Twenty Three (Full Site Editing theme) and block editor, so I'm looking for a block editor solution, not a php-solution (of which there are plenty).

I guess I have to modify the [Categories list block](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/categories-block/) somehow. Any ideas on how to do that?